Could not build wheels for pynfft, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects - ERROR
I'm facing this error while trying to install pynfft package on a conda environment using pip.
"Could not build wheels for pynfft, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects".
What is causing the issue and how can I install pynfft ?
I tried to install it via conda channels but nothing worked.
I'm on macOS Ventura 13.3.1

pynfft's latest version was released 10 years back.

Also, pypi says that it supports till python 3.4

https://pypi.org/project/pyNFFT/
Your newer python version could be the reason for not getting it installed.
You can download older versions of python for testing purpose.

I tried creating a new conda environment with an older version of python=2.7. I installed nfft, and while trying to install pynfft again I get this error :
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pynfft

@nan can you try with any python 3 versions mentioned?

If there's no python development headers available, gcc will exit with 1.
